Anychart's ganttChart extra line appears on data grid
I'm currently working on project management tool and for every project there is a gantt chart so when I 1st open a project and view the gantt chart everything seems normal the data is pretty normal even the chart is normal as you can see in this screenshot.
But when I try to switch projects and visit some other project at that time an extra line appears on the grid and also the dates on the time line vanish. Also, when I try to zoom in the bars of timeline overrides the grid its only when I refresh everything get back to normal.
Screenshot
The issue is only when I switch from one project to another. I also tried chart.dispose() but as of now nothing seems to work.
I also tried removeAllSeries() but I guess it doesnt work for ganttchart.

What code exactly do you run when you switch projects?

actually there's a parent component in which I can see the projects from there I usually select any project and in that project there is one another project called GanttChart where I display the Gantt for that particular project
